# If two verbs are in a row, is the first always an Auxiliary?

Tags: english, verbs, parts-of-speech, auxiliary-verbs

Consider the sentence:

> He **has** gone.

This is one of the example auxiliary verb sentences from:
"Radford, A. English syntax: An introduction, *Cambridge University Press*, **2004**"

**has** is an auxiliary verb, gone is a normal verb.

Compare to the sentence:

> He **has** a dog.

Here **has** is a normal verb.

I am wondering if seeing if two verb are in a row is a necessary and sufficient condition for the first to be an auxiliary?

Comment: The way the question is formulated, it seems to fit better at English.SE or ELL.SE.

Comment: @bytebuster Why ELL.SE? I can kinda understand English.SE,  but this seems way too advanced for ELL (though I don't really know, not going on ELL much).

Comment: Of course not. "I ran kicking the dog"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Your rule mostly works, but "in a row" fails to capture constructions like "He has definitely gone", where *has* is still an auxiliary.

In fact, trying to analyse syntax just by considering the surface sequence is usually doomed to failure.

Consider

> I am walking.

and

> I went walking.

Both have the same surface structure, but most analyses would consider *am* an auxiliary, but *went* not one: *walking* is a complement of the full verb *went*.

Comment: So, your first count example shows it is not sufficient, and the second shows it is not necessary, right?